Movie about man and woman who scam other women
The movie seems like it was made late 90s to early 2000s. 
The movie was about a man who met a woman at a funeral. It seemed like she had fallen in love with him and he seemed to like her. I remember that the man made his money by going all around the country meeting with single lonely women and somehow robbing them. I remember he took the woman he met at the funeral with him on his journey. 
There was a scene where the man hooked up with a older woman with the intention of robbing her. The man told the older woman that the woman that was with him which was the woman he met at the funeral was his sister or something along those lines. It ended up that the woman he met at the funeral got extremely jealous of the older woman and ended up killing her. 
Then I just remember that in between the movie the police were after that man and women. Then kinda towards the end the man hooked up with a mother that had a young little daughter. He again only had the intention of robbing her. But the same thing happened. The woman from the funeral got extremely jealous and ended up killing the mother and both the man and the funeral woman took the mother's daughter. 
I remember at the end the police finally got the man and the funeral woman but they found the daughter's body in a chest. I briefly remember they executed the woman at the end of the movie by putting her in the electric chair. 
After they stole the daughter they stole a dog from a old man at a fruit stand. Not sure if this helps but just throwing it out there. 

"old" really isn't specific enough. I've literally seen people here call a movie "old" that came out five years ago... and for me, it's not old if it didn't come out pre-1960s. Please make an attempt to be more exact about how old "old" is.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any  names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

This is most likely one of the many movies based on the true life 'Lonely Hearts Killers.'  The one I'm thinking of is Lonely Hearts (2006), which is just outside your time range.  However, most of the elements are there: 

The cops searching for them throughout the movie, 
The jealous girlfriend (Salma Hayek) who keeps going too far and killing the marks,
the taking of the child towards the end, 
the electric chair,
Oh, and even the dog at the fruit stand


@AssassinPictures: You're welcome!  To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. Thanks!
